# undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class, passing a form between views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Just starting to learn rails, and I'm trying to pass a form from one view to another view...I'm assuming the way to do this would be to use partial renders.

I want to pass the partial for the form contained in /users/form to index.html.erb in the home view. I just want to create a new user, but from index.html.erb in the home view.

Relevant Code:

_form.html.erb (in users view)

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :email %>
    <%= f.input :condition, :hint => 'what should we look up for you?'%>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, 'Begin curation' %>

  </div>
<% end %>
```

users model (user.rb)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :condition, :email, :name
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @users }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/new
  # GET /users/new.json
  def new
    @user = User.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'Thanks for sharing. We will be back with your curated information in 2-3 days time!' }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /users/1
  # PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

I'm sure this is an easy fix, I just don't know the syntax. I've checked other places, and haven't found anything that helps me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would bet my life you don't have an @user variable defined. SimpleForm needs an instance variable from the proper model to effectively do its magic with the input fields. It gives that error if your variable is not instantiated.

model_name is called on NilClass. NilClass is your @user.

Try this instead:

```
<%= simple_form_for User.new do |f| %>
...
```

### Update

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :prepare_user_form, only: [:index, :new]

  protected

  def prepare_user_form
    @user = User.new
  end

end


# _form.html.erb
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
...
```

Comment: I think that is it too, but how do i do that? do I just declare it at the top of my index.html.erb?

Comment: This worked! you are awesome! Thank you so much.

If you don't mind explaining, when are you supposed to use "@variables" instead of just the "Variable" name?

Comment: A form like this one using the Model.new would never update properly if it was for simple CRUD. Let's say this is your 'new' form and create action failed validation so you render the form again. Your newly instantiated variable @model would not be used in the form. You'd have a brand new Model.new object. FAIL. Even in your case, you should have a before_filter setting the variable on all actions sharing that _form partial. Let me update my answer. Basically, I use Model.new on AJAX forms only.

Comment: ok cool i think that makes sense to me. So if I had another view (called shopping let's say) and I wanted to add this form to the index. I would go into the controler, and add ":shoppin"g to the "only:" part of the before_filter, so the form would use the same variable in that rendering of the form as well?

Comment: If it's the same controller yes. Your example would make sense if it were to be the :search action of the UsersController. That's why I tend to force a lot of these partial _form to be AJAX. You update the Dom so no need to pass that @user variable around